# Android Studio 3 - Override Gradle Version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm setting up my app to migrate to Android Studio 3, but I'm running into some issues with the gradle version.

The docs say to [upgrade to at least Gradle 4.0-milestone-1](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#update_gradle) but I want to keep these migration changes on a separate branch until it's stable. That way I can use AS 3.0, and if something doesn't work I can quickly switch back to using 2.3.

The problem is that I can't find any way to override the gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` so that for AS 3.0 it'll use `4.0-milestone-2` and for AS 2.3 it'll use `3.X`.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: Add it to the Git and just have the versions on each branch.

Answer (score 1):

The file you want is called `gradle-wrapper.properties` **not** `gradle-version.properties`. You will find this script in the Gradle Scripts branch in Android Studio (in the Android view).

[Update gradle-wrapper.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flNda.png)

In this file, change the line

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip`

to read

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-rc-2-all.zip`

This will change Gradle-wrapper to use Gradle 4.0-rc-2 rather than 3.5 (obviously, replace the version numbers with the versions you use/want).

When you build your app with `./gradlew assembleRelease` it should now use whatever version you configured in `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Comment: The filename was correct in my project; I just typed it wrong. In any case, this doesn't have anything to do with overwriting it.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the Git and just have the versions on each branch.

Comment: You answer seems much like a comment to me!